# Should I store JWT token within the authentication cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, jwt

I am using the default Cookie Authentication provided by ASP.NET Core to sign in a user from an MVC web app. After the user has logged in, I try to access a Web API (in new project) which requires authentication via a JWT token. This API contains endpoints for fetching some student related information and also is responsible for authenticating the user and generating a JWT token.

So, from the Web App project I am just making API calls for authentication using the Refit library and getting the JWT token. Now, once the user is authenticated I redirect him to the `/students` endpoint which makes call to an API.

Now, my question is how should I access the generated JWT token in the Action after the user was redirected. I used the following way:

1. Get the JWT token and store it in a `ClaimsIdentity`.
2. Use `HttpContext.SignInAsync` **(cookie authentication)** to sign in the user. Now, the cookie on the browser will also contain the JWT.
3. After redirection, we will receive the Claim from `HttpContext.User` and use the token to make API requests.

So basically, I use cookie authentication on the frontend and use JWT authentication on the API side.

So, is it Okay to store the JWT token as I did inside the authentication cookie?

Comment: That is the way it is suppose to work.  The cookies are shared by all http connections by the user.  They are in the user stores area which is temp space in the user folder.